# How to make a for loop call an If statement every Increment of 20 AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, for-loop

Hey Everyone so I was wondering How I can make my If statement for efficient rather then creating multiple if statements for the same event.

So basically I have a If statement Like so:

```
if (nScoreJellyBeans == 20)
                {

                    //Add Chocoloate bunny
                    chocolateBunny = new mcChocolateBunny();
                    stage.addChild(chocolateBunny);
                    chocolateBunny.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
                    chocolateBunny.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - 90;

                    eggBar.destroyResourceEgg();

                    tChocolateEggTimer.start();

                    tEggTimer.stop();
                    tJellyBeanTimer.stop();
                    tBlackEggTimer.stop();

                    //Clear all eggs off the stage
                    for each(egg in aEggArray)
                    {
                        egg.parent.removeChild(egg);
                        aEggArray = [];
                        //egg = null;

                    }


                  }
```

Now in the same Function there are multiple of these exact If statements but they change when the score is incremented by 20.

So the Next IF statement would be `if (nScoreJellyBeans == 40)` so on and so on.

So how could i make it instead of making all these IF statements I would just have one loop that handled all the information in the If statement every time the `nScoreJellyBean` is incremented by 20?

I had an Idea of creating a for loop but not too sure how I would do it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: here is an idea, it might work...count the number of iteration using an integer counter, and divide it by 20 , if you get an integer in return do your functionality ,  ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use condition like that

```
if (nScoreJellyBeans % 20 == 0)      //this will work for zero also
```

use

```
if (nScoreJellyBeans % 20 == 0 && nScoreJellyBeans>0)    //for greater than 0 and multiple of 20
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was perfect. Thought I needed a for loop or something. So I am using your second answer. What exactly is the difference? the first one works for zero as well as the second one corrent?

Comment: Yes you got that right, We are getting remainder here, for e.g when nScoreJellyBeans = 40, it will divide 40 by 20 and check remainder as it is completely divisible so remainder will be 0, and when nScoreJellyBeans = 0, then also remainder will be 0 so we are checking  that it should be greater than zero in second condition.
So Second condition will run only when 'nScoreJellyBeans' is multiple of 20 and greater than 0.

Comment: Awesome thanks for all the information. No problem thanks for all the help and details! I appreciate it